# Can a 20.04 installation use the swap partition I set up for 18.04?

Tags: partitioning, swap

When I installed 20.04, I did not include a swap partition. I thought it would use the swap partition I created when I installed 18.04.

Now I am not so sure, because of the message that is printed during boot (topic of another question):

"Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed"

The suggestions I received in response to that question indicate that the error message can be ignored as long as my system boots. It does.

As I need swap because of large simulations, I would like to know if this "Initramfs" message might have something to do with there being no swap partition in the extended partition on which 20.04 is installed.

More importantly: Will the 20.04 system use the swap partition that I created for 18.04? Or do I need to create a swap partition on the same extended partition on which 20.04 is installed? There are now two partitions in that 20.04 extended partition. (If I have the terminology correct.)

Both systems are on the same physical disk, if that matters.

Thanks,
Tim

The following was added in response to a comment by Organic Marble, requesting /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=98c25f4b-2ac2-41cc-bf8f-9d6667197b05 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=96A9-436B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=d406105e-db74-471d-8949-833e6fdd262d /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=9335a211-26dd-415e-9cf2-fc0db3513574 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The following was added in response to heynnema:

tscale:~$ free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       2.2Gi        15Gi        57Mi        13Gi        28Gi
Swap:          97Gi          0B        97Gi
```

The info from /etc/fstab is above.

So, does it look like my 20.04 install (not an upgrade) is using the existing swap partition? Yes, it is 97 Gb, as I have 32 Gb of ram and was going to try hibernation. And I have extra disk space.

The following was added in response to heynnema's suggestion to execute
update-initramfs:

tscale:~$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
[sudo] password for tscale:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdc2
I: (UUID=9335a211-26dd-415e-9cf2-fc0db3513574)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

I rebooted after running the command. The same message came up.

The following is in response to a suggestion by Organic Marble:
tscale:~$ swapon -s

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb2                               partition   102399996   0   -2
```

And gparted indicates /dev/sdb2 is the swap partition "for 18.04".

Though I don't know what the priority response(s) mean, it looks like my code might use the existing swap partition.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of `/etc/fstab`. This should point to the swap (file or partition) currently being used by your system.

Comment: So it looks like you have a swap partition set up. To double check it, you can type `swapon -s` in a terminal to get the current status.

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `grep -i resume /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: heynnema: Response to first command: No such file or directory. Which is true; conf.d is empty. The grep command returned nothing.

Comment: I do have a 97 Gb swap partition that I set up when I installed 18.04. I "was told" that I did not need to set up a swap partition for 20.04; as it would take care of swap files. So I didn't.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Show me `ls -al /swapfile`.

Comment: heynnema: That file does not exist. A search for "swapfile" from /, yields several swapfiles in /snap: For example  /snap/core18/1885/etc/default.